# Run cron task at specified day of week but at any time

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I ran into trouble with cron. I need to run task on my desktop but the thing is I can't guarantee that my computer will be turned on in specified time.

For example I need to execute task weakly

If I specify

```
* * * * 6 user my_very_useful_task
```

*my_very_useful_task* will be executed every minute on Sunday but I need only once

If I specify

```
0 9 * * 6 user my_very_useful_task
```

*my_very_useful_task* will be executed in 9:00 AM, but I can't guarantee that computer will be turned on in this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **anacron**. From the *man anacron* page:

```
  Anacron can be used to execute commands periodically, with a  frequency
   specified in days.  Unlike cron(8), it does not assume that the machine
   is running continuously.  Hence, it can be used on machines that aren't
   running 24 hours a day, to control daily, weekly, and monthly jobs that
   are usually controlled by cron.
```

You can find a concise introduction [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/05/anacron-examples/#more-7606). At any rate, modify the /etc/anacrontab file
as follows: create a line with this format

```
 period   delay   job-identifier   command
```

Period is how often you want the job to run, acceptable values are 1 (daily), 7 (weekly), N (= every N days); delay is the time in minutes after boot the job has to wait before being executed; job-identifier is a file in the directory /var/spool/anacron where a record of the last execution of the command will be kept. Lastly command is the command you want to execute.

An example of a line in /etc/anacron is

```
  1 10 test.daily /home/my_name/bin/my_command
```

This will execute the command /home/my_name/bin/my_command daily (the option 1), leaving a record of its execution in /var/spool/anacron/test.daily, and, if at the time of the execution the pc is odwn, it will wait for 10 minutes after the next boot up to execute the command.